# How to remove locale string from sitemap for default language in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, next.js, internationalization, sitemap

I display my website in two languages: French and English.
I built my sitemap and I realised instead of having in my `sitemap.xml` this:

```
/blog
/en-US/blog
```

I have :

```
/fr-FR/blog
/en-US/blog
```

I would like to remove the `fr-FR` string from my sitemaps because it causes a duplication of page which is bad for SEO.
How can I do that? Also how to indicate canonical pages on an XML ?

Here is my i18n config:

```
i18n: {
    locales: ["fr-FR", "en-US"],
    defaultLocale: "fr-FR"
 }
```

And my `getStaticPaths` look like this:

```
export async function getStaticPaths({ locales }) {

    const products = await fetchAPI(`/products`);
    const productsData = await products;

    const resProductsEn = await fetchAPI(`/products?${enTranslation}`);
    const productsDataEn = await resProductsEn;

    const paths = []

    productsData.map((product) => paths.push(
        { params: { slug : product.slug} }
    ))

    productsDataEn.map((product) => paths.push(
        { params: { slug : product.slug}, locale: 'en-US'}
    ))      
    
    return {
      paths,
      fallback: true
    };
}
```

I use [next-sitemap](https://github.com/iamvishnusankar/next-sitemap) to generate my sitemap - `next-sitemap.config`:

```
module.exports = {
    siteUrl: process.env.FRONT_END_URL,
    generateRobotsTxt: true, 
    exclude: [
        '/test', 
        '/commande', 
        '/forgotten-password', 
        '/reset-password',  
        '/panier', 
        '/mon-compte', 
        '/mon-compte/*',
        '/fr-FR',
    ],
    robotsTxtOptions: {
        additionalSitemaps: [
            `${process.env.FRONT_END_URL}/sitemap.xml`,
            `${process.env.FRONT_END_URL}/server-sitemap.xml`,
            `${process.env.FRONT_END_URL}/en-server-sitemap.xml`
        ]
    }  
}
```

A more concrete example:

```
<url><loc>https://www.website.com/fr-FR/questions-reponses</loc><changefreq>daily</changefreq><priority>0.7</priority><lastmod>2021-12-03T18:26:08.673Z</lastmod></url>    
<url><loc>https://www.website.com/en-US/questions-reponses</loc><changefreq>daily</changefreq><priority>0.7</priority><lastmod>2021-12-03T18:26:08.673Z</lastmod></url>
```

Comment: I'm using next-sitemap from https://github.com/iamvishnusankar/next-sitemap
I build my app, then execute "postbuild" and links are automatically generated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`transform`](https://github.com/iamvishnusankar/next-sitemap#custom-transformation-function) property in `next-sitemap.js` to remove the default locale from the generated paths.

```js
module.exports = {
    // Other `next-sitemap.js` config here
    transform: async (config, path) => {
        return {
            loc: path.replace('/fr-FR', ''), // Remove `/fr-FR` from paths - could get value from i18n config to make it dynamic
            changefreq: config.changefreq,
            priority: config.priority,
            lastmod: config.autoLastmod ? new Date().toISOString() : undefined,
            alternateRefs: config.alternateRefs ?? []
        }
    }
}
```